# Checking Resiprok Data In Excel

Tags: excel

Need help.

How to check the reciprocal data in excel. The case something like this:

[image]

`b => a` is error because it's reciprocal (there is already `a=>b`) and so on..

thank you..

Comment: resiprok = reciprocal?

Comment: is the creation of a Visual Basic function an option?

Comment: use looping with VBA ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the COUNTIFS function to do this.

Assuming that the data excluding headers is in the range `A2:B8`, the first formula that you would need to enter in cell C2 would be:

```
  =IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,B2,B$2:B2,A2)>0,"error","")
```

This formula would then be copied down to the last data row.

`COUNTIFS` counts the number of times that a set of criteria are met in multiple ranges. If Criterion 1 is met in Range 1 AND Criterion 2 is met in Range 2 AND etc., then 1 is added to the `COUNTIFS` total.

In this case, we use `COUNTIFS` to check whether a particular person2 is in the Person1 range and whether the corresponding person1 is in the Person2 range.

Since you do not want the first occurrence of a person1/person2 pair to be counted as an "error", the `COUNTIFS` is applied to an expanding range that grows to include each additional pair that is checked but does not include any pairs further down the list.

For example, in the first formula in cell C2, the `COUNTIFS` is applied only to the range `A2:B2`, in the second formula in cell C3 it is applied to `A2:B3`, and so on.

In other words, we are looking at all prior pairs to see if the current pair is a reciprocal of any one of those pairs.

If the formula finds a reciprocal pair, which will be indicated by a `COUNTIFS` value > 0, then "error" is returned.

[image: formula with results in worksheet]


The formula just given will also return "error" if the current row contains a previously encountered reciprocal pair. Thus, you could get the following:  `b->c ""` ... `c->b "error"` ... `b->c "error"`. If instead you want that only the reciprocal of the initially encountered pair be treated as an "error", then a more complicated formula is required.

```
  =IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,B2,B$2:B2,A2)>0,IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,B2,B$2:B2,A2,C$2:C2,"error")>0,"","error"),"")
```

This revised formula checks whether the reciprocal of the pair in the current row has been previously encountered and marked as an "error." If it has, then the current pair is not marked as an "error".

[image: revised formula with results in worksheet]

Comment: I think it will not work when you put another b->c pair at the end of the list.

Comment: It will return an error for that pair because it is a reciprocal of the previously encountered c->b pair. I guess it is a question of whether that is a result that @Philips desires.

Comment: IMO it shouldn't be marked as an error because at row 5 it is ok. But you are right, @Philips must say what he exactly wants.

Comment: You make a good point, though. Will amend my answer to deal with that circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

I found my previous post won't work in all cases , e.g. when I put "d" into B6.

So I made another solution base on concatenating of values. Idea is that i concatenate values in column A and B (column D = `=CONCATENATE(A4;B4)`). I concatenate column B and A in column E (`=CONCATENATE(B4;A4)`).

And I look for the position from column E in upper rows of column D (`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(E5;$D4:D$4;0));0;MATCH(E5;$D4:D$4;0))`).

And I have to make another control for repetitive occurence of "good" relation (without that it would fail in row 11). So column G = `=IF(F5>0;INDEX($F4:F$4;F5);0)`.

In Column I there is a final evalutation `=IF(AND(F4>0;G4=0);"error";"")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using built-in functions - I split it into several columns (to be more clear for understanding) but it could be merged into one big complex formula.

[image]

In column D I check, if value from B column is present in upper rows in column A.

`=MATCH(B3;$A$2:A2;0)`

In column B I'm doing the same in reverse.

`=MATCH(A5;$B$4:B4;0)`

If value is not presented MATCH returns error #..., so in columns G and H I change this into 0.

`=IF(ISERROR(D5);0;D5)`

In column J I check if both positions are equal and if they are not zero.

`=AND(G5>0;H5>0;G5=H5)`

If in column J is TRUE then I print "error" in column L.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Actually this wouldn't work if letter "d" was in B6. The reason is that MATCH() function looks for the first occurence - and this is the weakness of that solution.